# Can I tell a dockerfile to write a file to the host?

Tags: docker

I am trying to use docker to build my project in a specific environment, but I am wondering if there's a way to avoid having to `docker run -v [mypath]:[workdir] -it [name]` to simply get some files out.

Can I tell a dockerfile to run some commands and then copy the resulting files to the host?

Comment: The volume/mount approach is likely what you want. Is there a reason you'd prefer not to go this route? You can also use `docker cp` to move files between containers and the host file system but I've only used this for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

No, images and containers are intentionally isolated from the host's filesystem, and there's intentionally no way for an image to read or write files on the host without being explicitly granted the privilege in a `docker run -v` option.

If your real goal is to run something to interact with files on the host then you'll often be better off installing and running it directly on the host than writing the very long `docker run` command line (and needing root privileges to do anything).

Answer (score 0):

You can't write file directly to you host system. But you can still achieve that by printing your result into console, and the write it directly to your file.

Take an example of this docker image: `docker/whalesay`. when you run `docker run docker/whalesay cowsay Hello there!`, It will print into console the text `Hello there!` and the whale together. So you can write these thing back to your file by doing:

```
docker run docker/whalesay cowsay Hello there! | tee ./somefiletowrite.txt
```